# How to write test for chef make install

Tags: testing, chef-infra, test-kitchen, inspec

I am trying to write some tests for a chef Nginx cookbook. I have come to a block. I need to write a test for the code below. I can test for the `core_lock` released. I am unsure how to test for the `make install` as well as `./autogen.sh` and `./configure --enable-standalone-module`

The docs have not been too helpful since this is a bash command the docs are a bit sparse.

**Code need test for**

```
bash 'compile_modsecurity' do
  cwd modsec_compile_path
  code <<-EOH
    ./autogen.sh
    ./configure --enable-standalone-module
    make
    make install
  EOH
  action :nothing
  notifies :run, 'bash[release_core_nginx_lock]', :immediately
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You would write an InSpec test block that uses a `command` resource to try and actually run `nginx`. Usually you do this with something like `--version` and then confirm that it looks correct. You can then try starting the service and use an `http_request` resource to connect to it on localhost and get some content.

Comment: Wow thanks, you solved a few issues for me without knowing. The `http_request` was something I just started looking into.

Comment: I tried to check for the nginx version how you said but I am not seeing Nginx in my system at all but a `service` check shows it is enabled and running but nothing else shows it as there. Is it possible to be getting a false positive on the enabled and running check?

Comment: Don't bother checking services, what matters is the HTTP GET. That either works or it doesn't.

Comment: Okay, why would it show up as there with a service check but not with a get request request.

Comment: Because your recipe is broken?

Comment: Far as I know it works in production. When I asked the coworker who wrote it they said likely because it runs as part of a runlist.

Comment: I don’t understand but this is now well outside the scope of SO comments. Jump on slack if you need more open ended help :)